# Authenticate linux client app to windows server app via kerberos or any secure protocol

Tags: c++, linux, authentication, kerberos, handshake

I need some guides or keywords I can use for my additional research.

Assume there are client and server apps written in C++. There is a possibility to pass blobs from client to server and vise versa. On windows, we can introduce Kerberos utilization, generating, processing such blobs, accepting it, impersonating threads, etc. There are some examples on msdn. It's not so simple, but I've managed to make it work.

But what if my client runs on linux machine? The simplest and unsecured way of authentication is to pass username/domain/password of user in raw format via blobs. But if I want to use Kerberos? So, the questions are:

- What preconditions do I need to have on client linux machine? My first thoughts were about some kind of samba/winbind things installed there. I heard samba authenticates to windows AD via Kerberos.
- Is there any good examples of performing Kerberos handshake on linux? I know there are some examples on MIT website. Should I use these ones? I guess it's not so easy to make it work in a right way and test it (actually I KNOW it from  my windows experience).

Answer (score 1):

The API you should investigate is GSSAPI. If the windows server application uses SSPI ( the windows version of GSSAPI ) then you should be able to write an interoperable client using GSSAPI. It really depends on exactly how the windows server uses SSPI though. See [MSDN SSPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380498(v=vs.85).aspx) for some details.

The MIT kerberos libraries are available with most linux distributions and have all the libraries you need to do GSSAPI with kerberos.

GSSAPI is a library for wrapping data, you still need to implement the resulting protocol exchange. Depending on exactly how the windows server is written this may be quite complex.

It is possible to use Active Directory as your KDC for writing linux client/server kerberos applications. Looking at the Linux Samba code should
help you understand some of the issues involved in writing a linux client
for windows based services.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Research seems to be huge... About c++ server which is on windows: it uses functions likeAcceptSecurityContext, InitializeSecurityContext, etc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374704(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't have any experience programming Windows, but I'm reasonably sure those calls coorespond to the equivalent GSSAPI versions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface